how to create conference for bridge call after answer
freeswitch, how to create conference for bridge call after answer, configure on dialplan. I tried all methods but no success:
<action name="api_on_answer" value="uuid_transfer ${uuid} conference:my_conference inline"/>

The call is terminated at B leg, hope to receive help
